# Angular 2 location.back() on first loaded page redirect out of application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to add feature that when user selects login page, after successful login he will be redirected to previous page.

I used method back() from Location library.
Everything works fine till I open browser and type http://host/login. After successful login I am redirected to empty page, out of my application. Any suggestion how to prevent this. Or use something else?

//Edit 
The main problem, which I try to solve, is how to find out the referrer page (page before login page) which is not from angular application. How to retrieve this information to decide to redirect to Homepage instead back to last visited page.

Comment: You can use `skipLocationChange` when you redirect to the login page

Comment: I open login page as a first by typing full url address. I understand that `skipLocationChange` i can used if i go from angular app. So this tip do not solve my problem.

Comment: "The main problem, which I try to solve, is how to find out the referrer page (page before login page) which is not from angular application" - are you using OAuth? If so, the flow should be controled by OAuth itself.